# How to Use Holo.Light Theme in SherlockPreference Activity screen

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, preferenceactivity

I am trying to get my dialogs within my preference screen to utilize the Holo.Light theme.  I am also using ActionBarSherlock.  Any ideas how to do this?

Here is some of my xml:

```
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_metric"
    android:entries="@array/pref_wind_speed"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_wind_speed_values"
    android:key="pref_wind_speed"
    android:title="@string/speed" />
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_metric"
    android:entries="@array/pref_wind_direction"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_wind_direction_values"
    android:key="pref_wind_direction"
    android:title="@string/wind_direction" />
<ListPreference
    android:defaultValue="@string/default_metric"
    android:entries="@array/pref_wind_direction"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_wind_direction_values"
    android:key="pref_wind_direction"
    android:title="@string/wind_direction" />
```

...

Comment: Adding the theme in Manifest (under <application ..>) doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: No it does not due to me using ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that ABS has the light AlertDialog theme for you to use. [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere) does, though.

When using HoloEverywhere, simply add these to your theme:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/Holo.AlertDialog.Light</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Holo.Theme.Dialog.Alert.Light</item>

<item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/Holo.AlertDialog.Light</item>
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/Holo.Theme.Dialog.Alert.Light</item>
```

If not using HoloEverywhere, you can find these declarations here: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere/blob/master/library/res/values/styles.xml